# Verify Backup SQL Server database using SMO

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, smo

I'm using Vb.net 2013 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a backup database, and I want to restore with SMO. But before restoring I want to verify if this file that I want to restore is a valid SQL Server database backup and has the identical structure (tables , fields) with the database that my program uses.

I know about the `Restore.ReadBackupHeader` method, but I don't know what information it holds and how I can use it to test this header with the header of a correct database?

Thank you !

Comment: I think you can verify the integrity of a backup (that the backup file isn't corrupt), but I don't think there's any simple way to "peek inside" the backup to find out the **structure** of the database it contains - you'd almost have to restore it first in order to see what's inside.

Comment: I read this :http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.readbackupheader.aspx , but I don't know what information it holds and how I can use it to test this header with the header of a correct database?

Comment: It will give you things like (a) what database is in the backup, (b) what type backup is it and a great deal more - but all those things are really *meta* information about the backup. It will **NOT** show you which tables and what data is inside this backup ....

Comment: Ok , if I restore the database with a temporary name , how can I compare the restored database with my model database ? How can I check that both have the same table structure ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I do it in Powershell with smo and and backupdevise. I scan a directory for certain backupfiles and then check in the header what the name of the database is and where the database is from what server and date and so. Finally I map it to the right database and do a restore. 
See microsoft ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backupdevice.readbackupheader(v=sql.105).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

found this VB code

```
  'Declaration
  Public Function ReadBackupHeader As DataTable
  'Usage
  Dim instance As BackupDevice
  Dim returnValue As DataTable
```

returnValue = instance.ReadBackupHeader()

here is other code:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c8e5b271-f053-4d3e-bd39-3d2a89e55af0/version-of-sql-back-up-file?forum=sqlsmoanddmo

Here is my powershell at github code: https://github.com/patriklindstrom/Powershell-pasen/blob/master/Restore-Sql.ps1

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceItem]$backupDevice = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceItem") ($f.fullname, "File")
        #set param so the PercentComplete notification is updated every 10 sec

        $smoRestore.Devices.Add($backupDevice)
        $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
        #read db name, original sql server name and date from the backup file's backup header
        $smoRestoreDetails = $smoRestore.ReadBackupHeader($server)
        $DBNameFromBackup = $smoRestoreDetails.Rows[0]["DatabaseName"]
        $DatabaseList += $DBNameFromBackup
        $OriginalDBServer = $smoRestoreDetails.Rows[0]["ServerName"]
        $OriginalDBBackupDate = $smoRestoreDetails.Rows[0]["BackupFinishDate"] 
        $smoRestore.Database = $DBNameFromBackup
```

I would suggesst that you write to the description field version number or key /changeset from code repo when backup is made. Then you check it when you want to restore. You can see Header info with eg RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'E:\SQL\big_DB.bak'. I mean a mean database can contain 1000 tables and 30.000 stored procedures. How should you check them in your restore script?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. You said>"But before restoring I want to verify if this file that I want to restore is a valid SQL Server database backup and has the identical structure (tables , fields) with the database that my program uses". You need versioncontrol for that. I suggest that you write the version number or hashkey of the version to eg description field.

Comment: See here for list of fields available in backup and media headers: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/backup-and-recovery/how-to-get-information-about-your-backups/